# Use Native Perl to get data from a network service

Tags: perl, networking

I am trying to use the perl to get the data from a network service/API, like the [Delicious API](http://www.delicious.com/help/api) . Does anyone know how to use the native API (not module from CPAN) to get such XML format data from the network service/API?

Comment: *Native Perl* makes me think of *indigenous perl*, *aboriginal perl*, or *autochthonous perl* far moreso than it makes me think of *stand-alone perl*, *bare-boned perl*, *naked perl*, *primitive perl*, *austere perl*, or *crippled perl*.  It’s kind of a *miniperl* thing, I’d guess. ☺ Let’s just call a ♠ a ♠: really it’s **ɴɪʜ Perl**, eh? ☹

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you want to use [Net::Delicious](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aDelicious)?

Btw, you can use [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize) and [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aSimple) to parse responses.

Comment: I will use those module, but I want to know how to implement them

Comment: @Yongwei, then try reading the source code of Net::Delicious.  That's one of the advantages of open source.

Comment: The links given point to the documentation for those modules.

Comment: Yes, but you can download the source from there, or watch in online by clicking on the _Source_ link.